# Show that $f_n(x) = e^{-nx^2}$ converges uniformly in $[a, +\infty)$, where $a > 0$, but doesn't in $(0, +\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I don't understand why $f_n$ doesn't converge uniformly in the interval $(0,+\infty)$.

$f_n(x) = \frac{xn}{e^{nx^2}} \frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n} \ \  \forall x \geq 0$ and $\frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ independently of $x$. So isn't the convergence to $0$ uniform? What am I missing?

Comment: Your upper bound is wrong but the convergence *is* uniform. Calculate $f'_n(x)$ and then $\max_{x\ge0}f_n(x).$

Comment: The first derivative of this function converges to $f'(x) = 0$ uniformly on any $[a, +\infty)$ but converges only pointwise on $(0, +\infty)$, could that have been it?

Comment: So taking the first derivative we get that the maximum is achieved at $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$ I can see the uniform convergence for $[a, +\infty]$, but why in $(0, +\infty)$ it is only pointwise?

Comment: @RahidFayad Sorry, the function sequence in your question does converge uniformly, but the sequence $g_n(x) = {f_n}'(x)$ (converging pointwise to $g(x) = 0$) converges uniformly on $[a, +\infty)$ for any $a > 0$, but does not converge uniformly on $(0, +\infty)$. We can see that under the uniform norm we always have $\lVert g_n \rVert_\infty = 1$. I was suggesting that the question may have been meant to be about this sequence of derivatives.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I think the comments above have covered the question, but maybe it's worth adding that you write in the title is true for $f_n(x) = e^{-nx^2}$.

Comment: Noting that $\exp(-nx^2)>0$ for $x\in \Bbb R$ and $n \in\Bbb N$, the reason for the non-uniform convergence over $(0,\infty)$ is that for any $n\in\Bbb N$, $\sup_{x>0}e^{-nx^2}=1$, so that it cannot tend to $0$ when $n\to\infty$, while over $(a,\infty)$ for some $a>0$, we have $\sup_{x>a}e^{-nx^2}=e^{-na^2}$ which tends to $0$ when $n\to \infty$.